# Transforming XSL stored inside XML

Tags: php, xml, xslt

Having following **XML**:

```
<xsl:element name="input">
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:text>email</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:text>email</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:text>form-control</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="required">
        <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

How can I pass it exactly like that to **XSLT** with following output:

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="true"/>
```

I have already tried `xsl:copy-of` and `disable-output-escaping`. But none of them seems to work. Is it even possible to achieve that?

Thanks.

Comment: Is that really what your input looks like? With no namespace declaration binding the `xsl` prefix to a namespace? If so, you won't be able to process it at all, because it's not XML.

Comment: Like so many XSLT questions, it's not enough to have one example of your input. We need to know how the input might vary from this example. For example, can it contain instructions other than xsl:element and xsl:attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** XML input such as:

```
<xsl:element name="input" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:attribute name="type">
        <xsl:text>email</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:text>email</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="class">
        <xsl:text>form-control</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="required">
        <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

you could use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="xsl:element">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xsl:attribute">
    <xsl:attribute name="{@name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="true"/>
```

As you can see, the fact that the input is an XSLT fragment is largely irrelevant here. The only difference it makes is that you don't need to  define a new prefix for the input's namespace.